Are there ways to access files that minimize the impact MsMpEng.exe?
Are there ways to access files that minimize the delays caused by MsMpEng.exe?
I'm accessing the metadata of thousands of image files. Each time I access a file, MsMpEng.exe steps in to check out the file before letting my app access it. This is right and good and I don't want to subvert MsMpEng.exe or change its settings.
For example, a WPF/WPA trace shows that of the ~30 seconds it takes to read the metadata of ~1300 jpeg, ~23 seconds of that is spent waiting on MsMpEng.exe.

Are there ways to access files to minimize the impact MsMpEng.exe?
===
Edit with more info

This is for a Windows app that will run on end-users' machines, so changing the settings for MsMpEng.exe is beyond my reach. (Also, would you install an app that asked you to change your antivirus settings?)
This app reads the user's photos. That is, the images are not part of the app, so packing them into an archive won't work. (Interesting, though... I didn't know about that.)
SuperUser would suite questions about the OS or how to use Windows antivirus. This is about how to programmatically minimize the impact MsMpEng.exe will have on a running application. For example, maybe there is a way to give the OS a heads-up that you're about to ask for access to 1000 files, and it can clear those files in a batch rather than MsMpEng.exe stepping in between every individual file open request.
One thread reads files at a time. It's one because IO is the bottleneck (not CPU), which also leaves some system resources for whatever else the user has running on their machine.

File access code looks roughly like this... the FileStream part should be the only bit that matters to the OS:
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        var decoder = ImageUtilities.BitmapDecoderCreateLossless(stream);
        var frame = decoder.Frames[0];
        frame.Freeze();
        var frameMetadata = (BitmapMetadata)frame.Metadata;

        // Read metadata from frameMetadata
    }


"I'm accessing the metadata of thousands of image files" -- can you show us an example of that?

Note StackOverflow is for programming-related question. Your question is proably better suited on https://superuser.com

That being said, AFAIK MsMpEng.exe is basically the Windows default antivirus. AFAIK You can tell him not to analyse some file (though someone malicious might theoretically use this property for targetted attacks -- use at your own risk). An alternative solution is just to pack the images in archive files (all AAA games does that nowadays).

How many threads do you use for reading the images? Please post the code you use for reading an image file meta data. May be the way you open the file triggers Defender...
